# Appeared to have lost funds after recovering Blockchain wallet

Tags: blockchain, wallet

For the past six months I have been logging onto my Blockchain wallet through Touch ID without any problems .
However recently my iPhone crashed/restarted and the Blockchain app asked me for my password which I was unable to find / remember . But I had written down my 12 seed string . After going through the recovery phase (although I didn't verify email?) I was directed to what appeared a new wallet ? Which had a new wallet ID and had a completely empty balance . It appeared as though all my funds had disappeared .This "new" wallet (or maybe wallet ID) with an empty account seems to match my 12 string code? which is what I most worried about .
Am I doing something wrong or is there a solution to this ?

Would really appreciate any response 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me yesterday as well but under slightly different circumstances.

I set up my account through the app, logged my seed and everything else I needed and continued with purchases etc. Couple of days later I decided to run this on my Mac and spent ages trying to figure out the pairing process, it wouldn't work at all seemed to only want to pair I'm the other direction. So I decided to delete the app reinstall it and pair how it asked. When I did this both online and app balances were zero. A bit worried, but happy knowing I had the seed I ran through the account recovery and when I came up the balance was still zero!

I logged into Coinify separate and the transaction is still there! So strange.

Comment: this is a "me too" comment and does not help to the original question or the audience. Me too comments are usually flagged for deletion here, so maybe you want to re-phrase your reply? Alternativly you can create a separate question.